# Get request to a local IP address

Tags: python, https, ip

How can I send an **https** get request to a local IP address in python?

When I do:

`import requests`

`requests.get("https://192.168.23.10")`

I get this:

> SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:847)

Do I have to install a certificate so I can send https requests?

Comment: use `verify=False` --> `requests.get("https://192.168.23.10", verify=False)`

Comment: @Rakesh when I do that I get a handshake failure error : SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:847)

Comment: update your python to use 2.7.9 and above., You might face this issue in older versions of python.

Comment: @Kenstars I'm using python 2.7.12

Comment: can you try installing pip install requests[security] , and check if your problem persists.

Comment: @Kenstars I installed it but I still get the same error